# Force IE9 to pull the latest Compatibility View List?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is there any way to force an IE9 instance to pull the latest compatibility view list from Microsoft?

How often does IE9 refresh its compatibility view list?

Comment: Does it do it automatically? I think I've seen it in Windows Update as an optional update (or for IE8 at least).

Comment: I think the compatibility list is here: http://ie9cvlist.ie.microsoft.com/ie9CompatViewList.xml ... I assumed that IE regularly polls this list.